# DLL alternative for Ubuntu

Tags: java, dll, ubuntu, native

We had developed one Java project which used DLLs internally (specifically `Com4j.dll`). Now we have shifted to Ubuntu and that project has stopped working (obviously).

- Can anybody give me suggestion what should I be doing now so that the project runs on Ubuntu?
- Is there any alternate so that without making more changes, we can run that project on Ubuntu?

Comment: com4j is interop with Microsoft COM, so chances are you're actually using COM components too. You'll need to identify and replace those components in your code, not replace com4j. But FYI the Linux equivalent to a .dll is a .so.

Answer (score 3):

Linux also has dynamically loaded libraries (.dll), but they're known as shared objects (.so). So in general you'd simply recompile the dll as an so and you should be OK. It seems however, that you're using COM which is a non-portable technology created by Microsoft. You'd have to replace COM components with something that is available on Linux (e.g. CORBA).